# value of type 'Int' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

```
if(Int(textfield.text!)! != nil) { //value of type 'Int' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed.

  //Rest of the code
 }
```

Everything was working fine but yesterday I have updated my Xcode after that I'm getting this error. Please help.

Comment: Because if you use `Int("someValue")!`, you're already telling the compiler you are sure it's not `nil`, therefor the additional evaluation is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for `nil` just remove the trailing exclamation mark to keep the result of the `Int` initializer as optional.

```
if Int(textfield.text!) != nil {

  //Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked!! Do you know why I was not getting any error before?

Comment: I can't imagine that there was no warning/error before.

Comment: I'm sure there was no warning/error before. Anyway problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You're forcefully unwrapping the Int:

`Int(textField.text!)!` // This trailing exclamation (bang) is saying, trust me, this is not a nil

Then you're attempting to see if its nil or not with `!= nil`

I suggest that you do a proper unwrap of the optionals like so:

```
if let textInt = textField.text, integerUnwrapped = Int(textInt) {
  // Rest of the code
} else {
  // Handle if either the text or integer is actually nil
}
```

If for whatever reason textField.text gets a string of characters, this code will fail inside the else statement.

The way you're handling the forceful optional unwrap however will result in a crash.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I will try it. This textfield will not accept any values other than numbers.

Comment: Its good practise to avoid using the ! sign to unwrap, although I use it when I'm lazy haha